# Visual Studio 2010 queries registry HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion\PublisherPolicy\Default\

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010

So when I shut down Visual Studio 2010, I see it hangs around in [Task Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Manager) taking 50% (dual core), so I used [Process Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Monitor) to check what it did. So during this cpu spike, which lasts atleast 10 seconds, I see that it queries:

```
4 820 events on HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion\PublisherPolicy\Default\policy.4.0.mscorlib.resources_nb-NO_b77a5c561934e089
4 820 events on HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion\PublisherPolicy\Default\v4.0_policy.4.0.mscorlib.resources_nb-NO_b77a5c561934e089
4 819 events on HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion\PublisherPolicy\Default\policy.4.0.mscorlib.resources_nb_b77a5c561934e089
4 819 events on HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion\PublisherPolicy\Default\policy.4.0.mscorlib.resources_no_b77a5c561934e089
4 819 events on HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion\PublisherPolicy\Default\v4.0_policy.4.0.mscorlib.resources_nb_b77a5c561934e089
4 819 events on HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion\PublisherPolicy\Default\v4.0_policy.4.0.mscorlib.resources_no_b77a5c561934e089
```

None of the keys exist.

To make it easier:

```
HKLM\...\policy.4.0.mscorlib.resources_nb-NO_b77a5c561934e089
HKLM\...\policy.4.0.mscorlib.resources_nb_b77a5c561934e089
HKLM\...\policy.4.0.mscorlib.resources_no_b77a5c561934e089

HKLM\...\v4.0_policy.4.0.mscorlib.resources_nb-NO_b77a5c561934e089
HKLM\...\v4.0_policy.4.0.mscorlib.resources_nb_b77a5c561934e089
HKLM\...\v4.0_policy.4.0.mscorlib.resources_no_b77a5c561934e089
```

Some stacktrace

```
0  ntkrnlpa.exe    CmUnRegisterCallback + 0x51c    0x822e5a0d  C:\Windows\system32\ntkrnlpa.exe
1   ntkrnlpa.exe    NtAllocateVirtualMemory + 0x35a3    0x82275ff5  C:\Windows\system32\ntkrnlpa.exe
2   ntkrnlpa.exe    ObCreateObject + 0x8c4  0x8226dab5  C:\Windows\system32\ntkrnlpa.exe
3   ntkrnlpa.exe    ObOpenObjectByName + 0x165  0x8227dec6  C:\Windows\system32\ntkrnlpa.exe
4   ntkrnlpa.exe    SeSinglePrivilegeCheck + 0x129c 0x8227bdf7  C:\Windows\system32\ntkrnlpa.exe
5   ntkrnlpa.exe    IoSetIrpExtraCreateParameter + 0x52b    0x82258afb  C:\Windows\system32\ntkrnlpa.exe
6   ntkrnlpa.exe    ZwYieldExecution + 0xb56    0x820861ea  C:\Windows\system32\ntkrnlpa.exe
7   ntdll.dll   ZwOpenKeyEx + 0xc   0x77da5d24  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
8   kernel32.dll    RegKrnGetGlobalState + 0x11e    0x779ecf08  C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
9   kernel32.dll    RegOpenKeyExW + 0x135   0x779ed0a6  C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
10  kernel32.dll    RegOpenKeyExW + 0x21    0x779ecf92  C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
11  devenv.exe  devenv.exe + 0x1a17 0x2f751a17  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
12  clr.dll StrongNameFreeBuffer + 0xe2f9   0x70d82367  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
13  clr.dll GetCLRIdentityManager + 0x6611  0x71017d30  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
14  clr.dll StrongNameFreeBuffer + 0x6c46   0x70d7acb4  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
15  clr.dll StrongNameFreeBuffer + 0x56c1   0x70d7972f  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
16  clr.dll StrongNameFreeBuffer + 0x52cf   0x70d7933d  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
17  clr.dll StrongNameFreeBuffer + 0x2aa3   0x70d76b11  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
18  clr.dll StrongNameFreeBuffer + 0x239a   0x70d76408  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
19  clr.dll StrongNameFreeBuffer + 0x319b   0x70d77209  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
20  clr.dll StrongNameFreeBuffer + 0x32a4   0x70d77312  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
21  clr.dll StrongNameFreeBuffer + 0x25eb   0x70d76659  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
22  clr.dll StrongNameFreeBuffer + 0x28bd   0x70d7692b  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
23  clr.dll StrongNameFreeBuffer + 0x509b   0x70d79109  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
24  clr.dll CoUninitializeEE + 0x12c05  0x70cc0dcd  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
25  clr.dll StrongNameSignatureVerification + 0x256a0   0x70db2687  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
26  mscorlib.ni.dll mscorlib.ni.dll + 0x24e713  0x4c2e713   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\74353039393f68f4c068cc37f759e5be\mscorlib.ni.dll
27  mscorlib.ni.dll mscorlib.ni.dll + 0x24e4ea  0x4c2e4ea   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\74353039393f68f4c068cc37f759e5be\mscorlib.ni.dll
28  mscorlib.ni.dll mscorlib.ni.dll + 0x23d314  0x4c1d314   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\74353039393f68f4c068cc37f759e5be\mscorlib.ni.dll
29  mscorlib.ni.dll mscorlib.ni.dll + 0x23cf95  0x4c1cf95   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\74353039393f68f4c068cc37f759e5be\mscorlib.ni.dll
30  mscorlib.ni.dll mscorlib.ni.dll + 0x23cd51  0x4c1cd51   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\74353039393f68f4c068cc37f759e5be\mscorlib.ni.dll
31  mscorlib.ni.dll mscorlib.ni.dll + 0x23caba  0x4c1caba   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\74353039393f68f4c068cc37f759e5be\mscorlib.ni.dll
32  mscorlib.ni.dll mscorlib.ni.dll + 0x2bba5a  0x4c9ba5a   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\74353039393f68f4c068cc37f759e5be\mscorlib.ni.dll
33  clr.dll clr.dll + 0x21bb    0x70c921bb  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
34  clr.dll CoUninitializeEE + 0x6a3a   0x70cb4c02  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
35  clr.dll CoUninitializeEE + 0x6bdc   0x70cb4da4  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
36  clr.dll CoUninitializeEE + 0x6c11   0x70cb4dd9  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
37  clr.dll CoUninitializeEE + 0x6c31   0x70cb4df9  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
38  clr.dll StrongNameSignatureVerification + 0x705d    0x70d94044  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
39  clr.dll StrongNameSignatureVerification + 0x71b8    0x70d9419f  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
40  mscorlib.ni.dll mscorlib.ni.dll + 0x2bb931  0x4c9b931   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\74353039393f68f4c068cc37f759e5be\mscorlib.ni.dll
41  mscorlib.ni.dll mscorlib.ni.dll + 0x2bbc18  0x4c9bc18   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\74353039393f68f4c068cc37f759e5be\mscorlib.ni.dll
42  clr.dll clr.dll + 0x21bb    0x70c921bb  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
43  clr.dll CoUninitializeEE + 0x6a3a   0x70cb4c02  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
44  clr.dll CoUninitializeEE + 0x6bdc   0x70cb4da4  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
45  clr.dll CoUninitializeEE + 0x6c11   0x70cb4dd9  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
46  clr.dll StrongNameSignatureVerification + 0x3641a   0x70dc3401  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
47  clr.dll StrongNameSignatureVerification + 0x3651c   0x70dc3503  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
48  mscorlib.ni.dll mscorlib.ni.dll + 0x912338  0x52f2338   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\74353039393f68f4c068cc37f759e5be\mscorlib.ni.dll
49  clr.dll clr.dll + 0x21bb    0x70c921bb  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
50  clr.dll CoUninitializeEE + 0x6a3a   0x70cb4c02  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
51  clr.dll CoUninitializeEE + 0x6bdc   0x70cb4da4  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
52  clr.dll CoUninitializeEE + 0x6c11   0x70cb4dd9  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
53  clr.dll ClrCreateManagedInstance + 0xb08a   0x70d37ac5  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
54  clr.dll CopyPDBs + 0x3213   0x70e04e11  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
55  clr.dll CopyPDBs + 0x30c0   0x70e04cbe  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
56  clr.dll CopyPDBs + 0x3f99   0x70e05b97  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
57  clr.dll CopyPDBs + 0x4a93   0x70e06691  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
58  clr.dll AttachProfiler + 0x7b720    0x70eeacd8  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
59  clr.dll LogHelp_TerminateOnAssert + 0x24a69 0x70d66e61  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
60  clr.dll LogHelp_TerminateOnAssert + 0x24033 0x70d6642b  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
61  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0.ni.dll    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0.ni.dll + 0x19dbac 0x6524dbac  C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Microsoft.VisualStu#\51ec00387b2726668eecc731cf279ecc\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0.ni.dll
62  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0.ni.dll    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0.ni.dll + 0x85f42  0x65135f42  C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Microsoft.VisualStu#\51ec00387b2726668eecc731cf279ecc\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0.ni.dll
63  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0.ni.dll    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0.ni.dll + 0x85bd8  0x65135bd8  C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Microsoft.VisualStu#\51ec00387b2726668eecc731cf279ecc\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0.ni.dll
64  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.UI.Internal.ni.dll Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.UI.Internal.ni.dll + 0x5a8a9   0x638aa8a9  C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Microsoft.VisualStu#\7fc7b3a8346dc7e6dc904e41b0527313\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.UI.Internal.ni.dll
65  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0.ni.dll    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0.ni.dll + 0x8c094  0x6513c094  C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Microsoft.VisualStu#\51ec00387b2726668eecc731cf279ecc\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0.ni.dll
66  clr.dll StrongNameSignatureVerification + 0xf58a    0x70d9c571  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
67  clr.dll StrongNameSignatureVerification + 0xf450    0x70d9c437  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
68  clr.dll StrongNameSignatureVerification + 0xf4df    0x70d9c4c6  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
69  clr.dll StrongNameSignatureVerification + 0xf728    0x70d9c70f  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
70  clr.dll StrongNameSignatureVerification + 0xf664    0x70d9c64b  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
71  clr.dll StrongNameSignatureVerification + 0x61b23   0x70deeb0a  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
72  clr.dll StrongNameSignatureVerification + 0x4c3ef   0x70dd93d6  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
73  clr.dll StrongNameSignatureVerification + 0x4c471   0x70dd9458  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
74  clr.dll StrongNameSignatureVerification + 0x4c52c   0x70dd9513  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
75  clr.dll StrongNameSignatureVerification + 0x43cd5   0x70dd0cbc  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
76  clr.dll StrongNameSignatureVerification + 0x43ce8   0x70dd0ccf  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
77  clr.dll SetRuntimeInfo + 0x1eef 0x70e31964  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
78  clr.dll StrongNameSignatureVerification + 0x11f29   0x70d9ef10  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
79  kernel32.dll    BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x12  0x779eed6c  C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
80  ntdll.dll   RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0xef  0x77dc37f5  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
81  ntdll.dll   RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0xc2  0x77dc37c8  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
```

What is going on?

Comment: I have often ended up concluding (incorrectly) that registry access is taking time. Its most likely some disk activity that's waiting.

Comment: I have an issue now with vs2010 using up one core constantly. Process Explorer points to clr.dll!strongnamesignatureverification

Comment: @flq What language is your OS? What does Process Monitor report, especially about registry keys.

Comment: hmm, the issue has improved but is not perfect after the latest patch day with some changes to .net 4 - all very weird